# Symfony - query builder return closest data

Tags: php, mysql, function, symfony

I wrote a query.

In my db I have a field

`gps_location: string in format: 41.22,42,33..`

My feed should return data near that locations (like 50km).

I tried this.

```
public function getDataNearby()
{
    $near = 50;

    $query = $this->getDataRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->select('s')
        ->where('s.gpsLocation <= :near')
        ->andWhere('s.gpsLocation > :near')
        ->setParameter('near', $near)
        //->orderBy("abs(s.id)","ASC")
       // ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery();

    return $query;

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need some google search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this repository method to select a "Location" entity that is in a certain radius of another "Location" entity. Maybe you can modify it to your own needs.

```
/**
 * Find a location in a radius around another location
 *
 * @param  float $lat latitude
 * @param  float $lng longtitude
 *
 * @param int $km
 *
 * @return array
 * @throws NonUniqueResultException
 */
public function findNear( float $lat, float $lng, int $km = 1 )
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder( 'loc' );

    return
        $qb
            ->select( 'loc' )
            ->addSelect(
                '( 6371 * acos(cos(radians(' . $lat . '))' .
                '* cos( radians( loc.lat ) )' .
                '* cos( radians( loc.lng )' .
                '- radians(' . $lng . ') )' .
                '+ sin( radians(' . $lat . ') )' .
                '* sin( radians( loc.lat ) ) ) ) as dist'
            )
            ->having( 'dist < :distance' )
            ->setParameter( 'distance', $km )
            ->orderBy( 'dist', 'ASC' )
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult()
        ;
}
```